# How I can user current module id in visual designer

Tags: 2sxc

I have a module showing items from a query. I have a field for some entities adding current ModuleId, but I need to filter those entities in visual designer using ModuleId value. How i can get current ModuleId in Visual Designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found the solution, inside visual designer is possible to use token [Module:Id] this will work to filter entities with current module

Comment: great ;) best mark as answered for others who are lookin for this.